# The bolt of my pedal's crank arm broke, what could be the causes?

Tags: bottom-bracket, pedals

It broke while as I started pedaling when a redlight turned green.

In the pics it is possible to see that basically the metal broke! Was it just a poorly constructed product or are there some common causes that explain why this happened (like i should have unmounted it and cleaned the dirt out of the screwing lines sometimes or else..).

I wouldn't want this to happen to my other pedal.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Original pictures: https://m.imgur.com/a/awW3NgK

Thx

Comment: Most likely a manufacturing defect. Hope it did not cause you to crash.

Comment: I would suspect that the crank has been subjected to rough treatment in the past, either being dropped on its side a lot, or being struck by a car in your garage or whatever.  (I'm guessing the bike is 30 years old, and has quite a history to it.)  Prior to this failure, did the crank arm seem to be bent inward?

Comment: @Daniel R Hicks, the crank arm didnt't seem to have any defect. Actually the arm is good it's only the axis that broke. However i bought the bike second hand, and it's indeed an old bike

Comment: You need a better photo to look for fatigue or defects, two most likely scenarios . At least 2 X close up , 5 X if you can do it. From what I can see ,a fairly peculiar fracture face.

Comment: @incas - It's hard to tell for sure, but in your first photo the arm appears slightly bent.

Comment: I agree it is metal fatigue. It could have been caused by a pedal strike at some point in its past. I remember snapping a few crank arms in my youth, usually from pedaling to fast and hitting a curb while cornering.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "bolt" that broke is not a part of the crank. Your bike has a so-called square-taper bottom bracket and one side of the axle broke off. This axle is a solid metal part that runs from one crank arm through the bottom bracket shell to the other crank arm. It cannot be serviced and should not break. The most likely reason is metal fatigue.

You'll have to buy a new bottom bracket if it is a cartridge type or at least a new axle if is the cup-and-cone type.

Comment: Is it just me, or does the metal axle look like it is made of cast iron? The surface of the break looks very rough, too rough for steel. Cast iron is not a material should be used for axles...

Comment: @MadMarky You are right, it does look a bit like cast iron. However, I have no idea how bad that would be.

Comment: Square taper axles can be bought separately in different lengths, so there may be no need for a whole new bottom bracket. But then the broken bit may also be hard to get out of the crank-arm.

Comment: @Carel you are right, if it's a cup and cone type, the axle can be bought separately (and at least the crank looks old enough for that to have been likely). I don't think the broken bit should be that hard to remove though. If the crank bolt can be removed (threads unbroken), one can fixate the crank arm in a vise and hammer out the axle remnant with a punch.

Comment: @MadMarky - The axle (even if cheap) is made from hardened steel and, in a fatigue scenario, will develop a fracture surface like that.

Comment: @StefanS - Unless the bike has sentimental value it's likely not worth fixing.  It would likely cost US$100 to fix, and for that you can buy a new BSO or a somewhat better quality used bike.

Comment: That sort of matte finish suggests a fatigue fracture. Essentially, over enough stress cycles, metal can become more brittle. Eventually, cracks form and propagate. It takes a lot of cycles (millions) but possible with an old highly used bike.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I don't see how that has to cost US$100. If you have a friend or a bike-coop with the tools to remove the other crank arm and the bottom bracket, you can buy a new BB for something like 10-20€ online. If you have to pay a bike shop, you are right and it may not be worth it. Depends on the quality and condition of the rest of the bike.

Comment: @StefanS I'll do it myself yep! I already removed the broken axle, next step now is to figure out exactly what new axle to buy. Nothing is written on the axle. Would u know what information I have to get ?

Comment: @StefanS - I say that because the OP clearly has no bike maintenance skills (nor tools).  If indeed he can get the labor for free then it might be worth it.

Comment: @incas I don't know where you'd get the exact axle. Maybe there are engravings on it that can tell you more? If there are, that's probably a good next question. If you can't find the axle, there is always the option to buy a new bottom bracket. There are questions on this site pertaining to that already (a bit spread out), but essentially you need to find out the type of thread (english, italian, french, maybe something exotic), the width of the bottom bracket shell and the width and type (symmetric, asymmetric) of the axle.